# agregar un nuevo valor en el hasmap al momento de hacer un test en JUNIT

Tags: java, hashmap, junit-5

Se usa la librería de Mybatis para la conexión a la bd que se realiza por el mapper
El problema radica en que no puedo mockear el valor del HASHMAP donde devuelve el RESULTADO que se agrega al llamar al sp y siempre llega en NULL cuando realizo un test unitario.
A continuación les presento un modelo del código

Archivo de invocación al SP el cual retorna un INTEGER la KEY **resultado** del hashmap

```
     <!-- XML -->
<select id="countDashBoard" parameterType="java.util.Map" statementType="CALLABLE">
        { #{resultado, mode=OUT, jdbcType=NUMERIC, javaType=java.lang.Integer} = call BD.PAQUETE.AGREGAR(
                                    '${dato1}', 
                                    '${dato2}',
                                    '${dato3}')}
  </select>
```

Clase interface que realiza la comunicacion con el xml anterior

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper{
    public void agrega(Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

Servicio que realiza la operación de invocación y muestra del valor obtenido

```
 @Service
    public class MiServicio(){
        @Autowired
        private MyMapper myMapper;
        public Integer holaMap( String d1, String d2, String d3){
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("dato1", d1);
                params.put("dato2", d2);
                params.put("dato3", d3);    
            myMapper.agrega(params);
            
            Integer hola= (Integer)params.get("resultado");
            
            if(hola=1){
                System.out.println("hola");
            }
            return hola;
        }
    }
```

Clase de Test que estoy realizando para las pruebas

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DashBoardServiceImplTest {
@Mock
MyMapper myMapper;
@InjectMocks
MiServicio serviceImpl;
Map<String, Object> params;
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    @Test
    void testObtenerEstadisticasDashBoardPag() throws IsimplyException {
        params.put("dato1", "d1");
        params.put("dato2", "d2");
        params.put("dato3", "d3");  

        //given
        willDoNothing().given(myMapper).agrega(params);
        
        //when 
        Integer hola= serviceImpl.holaMap("d1","d2",);
        
        //then
        assertNull(hola);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para todos los que hayan tenido este incoveniente ahi les va la respuesta obtenida del chatgpt

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MiServicioTest {

    @Test
    public void testHolaMap() {
        // Crear un mock del objeto MyMapper
        MyMapper myMapperMock = Mockito.mock(MyMapper.class);

        // Crear una instancia del servicio MiServicio y establecer el mock
        MiServicio miServicio = new MiServicio();
        miServicio.setMyMapper(myMapperMock);

        // Crear un mapa de parámetros para la prueba
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("resultado", 1); // Agregar el valor de resultado esperado

        // Configurar el comportamiento del mock
        when(myMapperMock.agrega(Mockito.anyMap())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            Map<String, Object> argument = invocation.getArgument(0);
            argument.putAll(params);
            return null; // No se devuelve nada, ya que el método es void
        });

        // Llamar al método que se está probando
        Integer resultado = miServicio.holaMap("dato1", "dato2", "dato3");

        // Verificar que el mock fue llamado con los parámetros correctos
        verify(myMapperMock).agrega(Mockito.anyMap());

        // Realizar las aserciones necesarias
        assertEquals(1, resultado.intValue()); // Verificar el resultado esperado
    }
}
```